# issue in doing a telnet connection through ssh on to a linux device box?

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, telnet

We are facing trouble establishing telnet connection via ssh.  firstly I used rencissh library to establish ssh on to the linux box.

```
linux_box_ip/host/password : 192.168.4.127/admin/password12
```

Then, i try to do a telnet connection by calling tcp class,

```
tcpSocket = new TcpClient(host,port); 
host/port:  192.168.4.127/18080
```

but the connection is refused by the device.
After some stackflow post read, i understand we need to follow a sequence where you do a Ssh and then do a port forwarding and then do a telnet.
so i tried the below  code.

```
connectionInfo connNfo = new connectionInfo("192.168.4.127",22,"admin",
     new AuthenticationMethod[]{
           new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("Admin","password12")
       });
using(var sshclient = new SshClient(connNfo )){
     sshclient .Connect();
var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost",22,"192.168.4.128",18080 );
sshClient.AddForwardedPort(port);


    port.Exception += delegate(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());
    };
    port.Start();
```

So, once this is done i do a tel net on the host/port: 192.168.4.127/18080

```
tcpSocket = new TcpClient(host,port); 
host/port:  192.168.4.127/18080
```

Again it seems to fail with the messsage:

> NO connection could be made, target machine refused it

How do i do seamless ssh and then telnet on the device box ?? am i doing something wrong ?